# AS3 button inside movieclip used as part of a scrollpane- doesn't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, scrollpane

I'm a beginner actionscripter, so I hope you will take that into account when replying. The problem I am having is that a client has asked me to place a call to action button inside a textbox that scrolls. My idea was to create a movieclip containing the text and the button, then place that movieclip inside a scroll pane. I've been monkeying around with it all day and have made minimal headway. I'm not even sure of the best way to accomplish this.

If one of you learned actionscripters out there could point me in the right direction, perhaps I can find my own solution.

The client wants me to use custom icons for the scrollbars, and as altering a scrollbar component seems like such a PIA, I'm trying to avoid using components.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you messed with scrollpane.mouseChildren = true? Also have you added a MouseEvent.Click listener to your button? If you can, show some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the button show up when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the textbox? Putting the button actually "in" the scroll box doesn't seem very clean, especially if the user then scrolls back up again then the button would be hidden.

Assuming on your stage have a TextField named "text_txt", a SimpleButton or MovieClip named "someButton_mc" and a UIScrollBar (from the components) named "scrollBar_mc"; 
In the scrollbar's properties set "scrollTargetName" to "text_txt" to link the scroll bar to the text field. Then code something like this:

```
import fl.controls.UIScrollBar;
import fl.events.ScrollEvent;

//Hide the "Call to action" button
someButton_mc.visible = false; 

var sb:UIScrollBar = UIScrollBar(scrollBar_mc);

//Monitor when user scrolls
sb.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, didScroll);

function didScroll(evt:ScrollEvent):void {
    //Check if user scrolled to bottom
    if(sb.scrollPosition == sb.maxScrollPosition){
        //Show button if at bottom
        someButton_mc.visible = true; 
        //Cleanup event listener since no longer needed
        sb.removeEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, didScroll);
    }
}
```

Skinning the scroll bar isn't as bad a task as you'd think, at least once you figure it out. There are plenty of tutorials out there for skinning or making a custom scroll bar. Let me know if that helps or if I misunderstood.

One more thing: make sure "text_txt" is multiline and has a good amount of text for testing purposes.

Comment: Interesting proposition. I'm not sure the client will go for it, but I'll give it a shot in the morning... thanks!

Comment: With the button at the bottom, what is the goal of the client exactly?

Comment: There is already another call to action on the page. This is simply another one (albeit smaller) they can click on once they've read the text.

Comment: Although I thought it was a pretty cool thing, the client didn't like the button appearing at the end of the scroll. It looks like I'm back to embedding the button inside a swf. Any help as to how that can be accomplished would be great!

Comment: Still been searching the web for an answer to this... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your text and button to a scrollPane via actionscript. A Good tutorial showing the basics can be found here: http://www.parorrey.com/blog/flash-development/as3-add-dynamic-movieclips-to-scrollpane-component-using-flash/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I do not see the correlation between creating dynamic text boxes and accessing a button within a movieclip. Can you elaborate?